# google places api in listView in android with edittext in android

Tags: android, listview, autocomplete, google-places-api

I am working on google places api and have made a successful demo on the it,but thing is that i have developed it with autocomplete and need to do it in listview so can anybody please help me to do it?I need is change the list contents while typing in the edittext.

**code**

```
 AutoCompleteTextView autoCompView = (AutoCompleteTextView)getActivity().findViewById(R.id.autoCompleteTextView);

        autoCompView.setAdapter(new GooglePlacesAutocompleteAdapter(getActivity(), R.layout.list_item_one));
        autoCompView.setOnItemClickListener(this);
```

Answer (score 0):

Use Textwatcher for same on update text fetch the data from place api and call notifydatasetchanged

Comment: I am newbie can u help me little more,?please